# How to record screen when app is in Background ios 8.4(Swift)

Tags: iphone, swift, ios8, background

I am not able to record screen in my swift app once the home button of iphone is clicked(i.e. when the app is suspended)

> Explanation:

In my Swift App,I have created buttons to record/stop, declared an object(myScreenView) of bridged Objective C Class as IBoutlet and connected it to my view.
When I click on record button,a bridged Objective C method is called
which records the screen.(the Code is as follows)

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
}

@IBAction func recordAction(sender: AnyObject?){
myScreenView.StartRecording()
}

@IBAction func stopAction(sender: AnyObject?){
myScreenView.StopRecording()
}
```

From the Above, I am able to record screen when my App is in Foreground but when the home button is pressed it stops recording.

> Actions taken:

1. Checked Audio and Airplay and Background Fetch checkbox in App Capabilities
2. Set "NO" to "Application does not run in background” info property.

Please Advice what is to be done to record screen when app is pushed to background.

Comment: When your app is in the background, it will stop receiving screen update events... even if you set it to run in the background. I don't believe there is a way to do what you want on iOS unless you can find a way to draw your view to an offscreen context while in the background... but I have a feeling that won't work either

Comment: @Good Doug Thanks for the instant reply, will try to draw my view using offscreen rendering and see if it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't possible. Once an app is closed, it cannot execute pretty much any code (with the exceptions of Push Notifications).

Application running in background is reserved for very basic functions (not camera recording - Im guessing because it would pose a security risk).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But I am not using Camera(Hardware), just capturing the view using AVAssetWriter.

Comment: Did you find any solution